# Re-creating iPad fling momentum in AIR (AS3)

Tags: iphone, ipad, actionscript, air

I'm creating an AIR app, but I realized that it doesn't seem to natively support the "fling" momentum. I thought I'd ask if anyone out there has created an object or plugin that would put this back in? Currently, on the objects I want to fling, I'm recreating the momentum, but it's not perfect yet. Could anyone put me onto the right path in doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own fling, and it works great.

I keep the last 3 `touchmove` locations and times in memory, then on `touchend`, I find the difference between the most recent and oldest `touch` in memory, to find speed and direction. Then I used `Actuate` to ease it a certain distance past that if necessary.

It took a lot of tweaking to make it feel natural, though.

Answer (score 0):

Greensock has a great plugin which works just like iOS native flick, and can be customized to work in an array of ways. Performance in Air is superb even on older iPads. For best results use BitMask.